# Response not successful doing a post request with retrofit2 in android app

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to send an object from my android app to my laravel web page. I´m using retrofit2 but when the post is done, the response is not successful and I don´t know what I´m doing wrong.
Here´s my apiService:

```
@POST("api/data/configuration")
    Call<Data> postConfigurationData(@Body Data datosNuevos);
```

And here´s how I make the post:

```
Call<Data> dataCall=service.postConfigurationData(datosNuevos);
                                    dataCall.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
                                            if(response.isSuccessful()){

                                                Toast.makeText(Course.this, "El post se hizo correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }else{
                                                Toast.makeText(Course.this, "El servidor retornó un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }


                                        }
```

When the post is done the toast that appears is: "el servidore retonó un error" which is the one in the else clause.
Any help?
Thank you.

EDIT
To try to get the error message

```
Call<Data> dataCall=service.postConfigurationData(datosNuevos);
                                    dataCall.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
                                            if(response.isSuccessful()){

                                                Toast.makeText(Course.this, "El post se hizo correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }else{
                                                try {

                                                    Toast.makeText(Course.this, response.errorBody().string(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(Course.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            }

                                        }
```

I get this error:
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed, url=http://192.168.68.108/api/data/configuration}

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the possible causes that could make your API call fail. You can check it in [Response#errorBody](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#errorBody--) for more details.
Since your question has not provided enough information to find a solution.

Comment: Thank you @fshdn19 . And how can I see the error? I have updated my post to show you how I have tried, but it doesn´t show any message. And what kind of code or information do you need to find a solution? Because I can provide whatever information you need.

Comment: `Toast` is not a good choice for log or debug, you should use `Log.d` instead.

Comment: I have used a different mehod and I get the error, and I´m trying to correct it but I don´t know how. The error is: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed, url=http://192.168.68.108/api/data/configuration}

Comment: As I see your log, the http-response-code is `405`, that means you used incorrect http method (It may be POST). You can ask your api provider to know which http method is correct (GET, POST, PUT,...). In some case, It's just a problem from your api provider. And they will fix it in server-side, you have to do nothing.

Comment: but I´m the api provider. I mean, I have developed the laravel web page I´m sending this data to. So that´s why I don´t undertand what can be going wrong.

Comment: Add your laravel api here, add `laravel` tag then some one else would give you a hand. Sorry I dont know laravel at all

Comment: I have found the error @fshdn19. I was doing the api wrong as you told me. In my laravel web page instead of doing a post request I was doing a get request.